# Installing ibus-avro in Fedora 35

Tags: fedora-33

How do I install ibus-avro package in Fedora 35?

I know here they have a guide to do so but I can't follow this because of a missing dependency "libibus-1.0-dev" and I can find any alternative name of it to work with this.

I have done -> sudo dnf install ibus-libs-1.5.25-6.fc35.x86_64

But this package doesn't help.

My exact error is this ->
[image: First 2 commands screenshot]
[image: Last one's screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## Install IBus Avro on Fedora 36 with Cinnamon DE

I installed it from source by following the official doc (the git clone command in the readme didn't work, I had to )

```bash
$ mkdir buildFromSource  # or some convenient location to keep your home clean
$ cd buildFromSource

 # git clone git://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro.git  # this didn't work for me :/
$ git clone https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro.git
$ cd ibus-avro

# stop, and install automake before following the readme

$ sudo dnf install automake # this installs aclocal, autoconf, and automake


$ aclocal && autoconf && automake --add-missing
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

I got some errors.

```bash
$ sudo dnf install ibus-devel ibus-libs  # no idea which one, or why I need. one of them resolved "missing ibus-1.0 error"
```

After that,

```bash
$ aclocal && autoconf && automake --add-missing
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr                      # yeah, I ran these 2 lines again just to be safe

$ sudo make install
```

Now avro should be installed on your system. If you can't find anything (like me), try logging out / restarting the computer.

Now we need to add avro in our input method. I'm using Fedora 36 with Cinnamon DE. It maybe slightly different in other DE (ie, Gnome, KDE, etc).

Select `windows key -> Input method selector`.

Initially, `no input method` was chosen. `Select Use IBus`. On the right of `Select Use IBus`, there is `Preference`. Clicking it opens
`IBus preference`. Now `Input method` -> `Add` -> `Bangla` -> `Avro`. I had to logout again to see the changes. এখন আমি ফেডোরায় বাংলা টাইপ করতে পারি! কিন্তু
`Gnome text editor` (the new one, not `gedit`) doesnot support avro :confused: At first, I was like, what went wrong! Later I found
সাব্লাইম টেক্সট / অন্য অ্যাপে বাংলা লিখা যায় ।